# PyCharm Code Completion Suggestions Not Disappearing Automatically

Tags: pycharm

I am a brand new programmer, just installed PyCharm for the first time and I think my version is bugged out or something. When I type in stuff into the editor the code completion suggestions do not automatically disappear when I hit space or continue typing, and I cant use the arrow keys to cycle between suggestions or hit enter to insert one. I have to manually click to get rid of them and I'm 99% sure this isn't how the program is supposed to function.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FLMO.jpg)

On every youtube video I watch in PyCharm, the suggestions automatically dissappear after the programmer is done typing. This is how I would expect my version to function, yet my suggestions stay on the screen forever and clutter up my screen very fast. The only way to get rid of them is for me to click manually which ruins the workflow. I don't understand what I did wrong, I haven't even started coding yet.

Comment: You are using some uncommon configurations for this to be happening or it may be a bug... What PyCharm version are you using and on what OS? Try changing the [code completion settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/auto-completing-code.html) to see if one of those settings solves your problem.

Comment: Could you please attach the logs folder zipped from **Help | Collect logs and Diagnostic Data** to the report? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-60028/Code-Completion-Suggestions-Not-Disappearing-Automatically Thank you in advance.

Comment: Same experience with `PyCharm 2023.1 (Community Edition) Build #PC-231.8109.197, built on March 29, 2023`; fresh install, no additional plugins installed. – Restart of PyCharm "fixed" this for me.

Answer (score 3):

For the interim I ended up disabling the autocomplete so I could work unhindered but I just had a response from JetBrains on this which fixed it for me.

I was advised to disable all plugins '***to avoid third-party affection***' (PyCharm > Settings > Plugins). The irony here is that mine was a fresh install so the only plugins are those bundled with the version I downloaded. I disabled the first one:
*Settings Sync* in the IDE Settings category and then saved which forced a restart of JetBrains, after which, once I had re-enabled the autocomplete it starting working. Oddly though re-enabling the Settings sync plugin didn't break it so not sure why it continues to work if the plugin was the issue.

Maybe it was just re-enabling the automplete that was the fix - feel free to try that first and let me know.